# UIScrollView sometimes lose its scroll when changing the height of UITableView inside

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have simple `UIScrollView` with two subviews: `UIView` and `UITableView` set in vertical mode. Both of them have their own height constraint:

I set it like this:

```
tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(height) //height is calculated based on number of cells multiplied 130

calendarViewHeightConstraint.constant = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!.traitCollection.isIpad ? 630 : 470
```

But sometimes when I scroll to the bottom, and then add a new cell to the table view and recalculate height it seems that scroll of scroll view is locked, and I can bouncing but the scroll disappear and I can only bouncing, although I know that I can scroll to the content above or below the current view on the screen. What may be the reason?

I really have to do this like this. There is no possibility to put my view inside table view header view.

This is where I recalculate height:

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    
        tableView.endUpdates()
        updateView()
        updateTableViewHeight()
}

private func updateTableViewHeight() {
    
    var height = goalFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!.count * 130
    
    height += 45
    
    if MyType.selected.hasMonthReport {
        height += 130
    }
    
    if MyType.selected.hasAnnualReport {
        height += 70
        height += 130
    }
    
    tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(height)
}
```

New cell is added inside delegate of `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: Can you provide code when you add new cell and recalculate height and etc.

Comment: I updated the question;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you need to change your calculation way of **height** of TableView like,

```
var height = tablView.contentSize.heigh // You can do + or - here 

// your other stuff of calculation.
tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(height)

self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // You need to call after change constraint.
```

Comment: On main view should I call `layoutIfNeeded`? Why I cannot calculate it like i do now?;) Simply I am interested in...